# Setting up Exim to forward mail

Tags: email, centos, exim

I'm trying to setup Exim on a fresh CentOS install so that it will receive mail for a collection of given addresses, and forward the mail respectively to another address. For example, receiving mail from me@example.com would be forwarded to me@gmail.com.

I figure this should be fairly straight forward... I had this working before with Sendmail, using the `virtusertable` - is there something similar I can do with Exim?

I'd also like to be able to send mail, but only for mail being sent from the local machine (i.e., from applications running on the server) - I don't need/want a publicly available SMTP server.

Are there any other settings I should bear in mind to make sure the mail server is secure? (i.e., prevent relaying) I'm assuming that it will be secure out of the box.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to use a redirect router.  Read the Exim Router specification, as it can do many things and thus can get quite complex.

Basically, you will need to set something up like this (untested)

```
sender_redirect:
  driver = redirect
  data = ${lookup{$sender_address}lsearch{/etc/exim4/sender_redirects}}
```

Then create a file in `/etc/exim4/sender_redirects` that contains the redirects in a line-separated colon-delimited format, like this:

```
me@example.com: me@gmail.com
```

Comment: Thanks Gavin, that definitely set me in the right direction. I'm using these lines:

    driver = redirect
    domains = dsearch;/etc/exim/virtual
    data = ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/virtual/$domain}}

where 'virtual' is a directory containing file 'example.com', and lines of the form: 'me: me@gmail.com'.

I also had to set my 'local_domains' to include 'example.com' (the trick with dsearch used above can be used here too).

Answer (score 5):

A variation on what Joe Freeman said, without using dsearch (which gave me unknown lookup type "dsearch" error):

In the beginning of exim.conf:

```
#Replace:
domainlist local_domains = lsearch;/etc/virtual/domains
#With:
domainlist local_domains = lsearch;/etc/virtual/domains : lsearch;/etc/virtual/forwarding_domains
```

In the section "begin routers" add:

```
sender_redirect:
    driver = redirect
    domains = lsearch;/etc/virtual/forwarding_domains
    data = ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/virtual/forwarding/$domain}}
```

In lsearch;/etc/virtual/forwarding_domains add your domains one per line:

```
example.com
```

And create /etc/virtual/forwarding/example.com containg:

```
me: me@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 4):

Exim4 also supports old-style `.forward` files, plus Exim-style `.forward` files which begin with `# Exim filter`. for example, to use the latter to forward to my backup account while keeping the original in my spool for POP3 access:

```
# Exim filter  <== do not edit or remove this line!

unseen deliver jcomeau_ictx@example.com
```

far simpler, and less dangerous, than monkeying around as root in the bowels of Exim configuration, IMO. full details on this are [here](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/filter_ch-exim_filter_files.html).