# Exim4: Configure catchall on multiple domains to forward mail to external addresses

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, exim, mail-forwarding

**UPDATE:** Thanks for responses on this but I'm going to drop exim and try Postfix.

---

My question is pretty similar to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/10279/setting-up-exim-to-forward-mail). I want to configure exim4 (on ubuntu 10.04) to forward/redirect all e-mail on a domain to an external address. My server hosts multiple domains. This is a pretty straight forward setup but I'm struggling to get it working.

Example:

`*@domain-a.com` > `whatever@gmail.com`

`*@domain-b.com` > `mr_bob@hotmail.com`

`*@domain-c.com` > `fred@flintstone.com`

I tried adding the following to `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template` but the director isn't matching:

```
domaina_director:
  driver = redirect
  domains = dsearch;/etc/exim4/fwd_domains
  data = ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim4/fwd_domains/$domain}}
  no_more
```

I've created the directory `/etc/exim4/fwd_domains` and in that, the file `domain-a.com`:

```
# cat domain-a.com 
*: whatever@gmail.com
```

**Update:** I'm not convinced this syntax is correct. More importantly, my director doesn't seem to be picked up before reaching this point.

Run `update-exim4.conf` & restart exim4.

Send test e-mail:

```
# mail fred@domain-a.com
Subject: jdhfdjks
dsfhjdshf
.
Cc:
```

This appears in `/var/log/exim4/mainlog`:

```
2010-07-07 22:21:51 1OWd03-0002Zv-Kx <= root@primarydomain U=root P=local S=332
2010-07-07 22:21:51 1OWd03-0002Zv-Kx ** fred@domain-a.com: Unrouteable address
2010-07-07 22:21:51 1OWd03-0002Zx-MB <= <> R=1OWd03-0002Zv-Kx U=Debian-exim P=local S=1111
2010-07-07 22:21:51 1OWd03-0002Zv-Kx Completed
2010-07-07 22:21:51 1OWd03-0002Zx-MB => /var/mail/mail <root@primarydomain> R=mail4root T=address_file
2010-07-07 22:21:51 1OWd03-0002Zx-MB Completed
```

My director doesn't fire and the e-mail ends up in root's mailbox. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Use a wildcard search 'lsearch*' instead of 'lsearch'. This will match the wildcards.

```
domain_aliases:
  driver = redirect
  domains = dsearch;/etc/exim4/fwd_domains
  data = ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch*{/etc/exim4/fwd_domains/$domain}}
  no_more
```

Alternatively you can put your aliases in /etc/aliases and use a router like this. You can change the domains option as appropriate for your configuration.  The above dseach would be appropriate.

```
domain_aliases:
  driver = redirect
  domains = ! +local_domains : +relay_to_domains
  data = ${lookup{$local_part@domain}lsearch*{/etc/aliases}}
  no_more
```

This requires aliases like:

```
*@domain-a.com : whatever@gmail.com
*@domain-b.com : mr_bob@hotmail.com
*@domain-c.com : fred@flintstone.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a little more invasive debugging:

```
exim -bv -d+verify fred@domain-a.com
exim -bt -d+route fred@domain-a.com
```

Your config looks sane (textbook even), more detail is needed on the failures.

Comment: verify: http://pastebin.com/0myFZ6mv route: http://pastebin.com/Nke2cbJD

Answer (score 0):

Your director needs to be above the local delivery router.

Comment: I've tried moving my director to the top of the `routers` section of exim4.conf.template but I still get the same problem - unrouteable address.

Comment: check what happens with exim -bt address@domain

Comment: $ exim -bt fred@domain-a.com
fred@domain-a.com is undeliverable: Unrouteable address

Comment: do you have it listed in your relay_domains

Comment: I don't think so: http://pastebin.com/4kLY2WC6

Answer (score 0):

At the [Exim docs](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch09.html) there's something about `lsearch` not expanding the wildcards, and using `wildlsearch` to expand the keys before searching. I think the way you are doing now would only match the address `*@domain-a.com`. Take a look at the examples in the docs.
Also, as a catch-all email, the router should be probably after all other meaningful routers, or it will catch valid emails before they are delivered.

Comment: There's no local recipients at the domain, it's all forwarded to gmail accounts.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably so obvious you already checked, but you never know.

Are you use by any chance using the split configuration scheme?

In that case you should ignore exim4.conf.template and go with /etc/exim4/conf.d/main/01_exim4-config_listmacrosdefs instead.