# What should I use for a forwarding only mail server?

Tags: ubuntu, email-server, mail-forwarding, aliases

I have a VPS running ubuntu 11.10 for a Django app, I want to be able to handle the email for one specific domain (already have the reverse lookup setup with the ISP for that domain), all I'm doing is forwarding email to different addresses, example first_name@mydomain.com -> first_name8384@gmail.com , second_name@mydomain.com -> second_name99348@yahoo.com ...  What should I use, and how do I set it up. I'm using Cherokee for the django app since I know someone's going to ask(I know nginx is supposed to do email, but I'm not switching).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for an [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) like postfix or exim.

Use any decent MTA. The fact that your server will not host the mailboxes itself but forward all mail to external servers should not influence much your choice: You just won't have to install additionnal software like pop server or webmail.

You can look at /etc/aliases to forward mail.

Answer (score 1):

This old ServerFault thread shows how to use the Exim MTA to implement this:

[Setting up Exim to forward mail](https://serverfault.com/questions/10279/setting-up-exim-to-forward-mail)

For this to work, the VPS will either need to be the primary MX for mydomain.com, or have another MTA forward mail to it directly.

Comment: Please provide content **here**. Link-and-run answers are strongly discouraged.

Comment: Understood. But apart from the no-links rule, that old post pretty much solves his problem.

Comment: The quality of the linked page really has no bearing on this. Without providing content here on how to solve the problem, your answer loses 100% of its value the instant that link goes dead. The mission of SE is not only to help others out in real time, but also to build a repository of questions and answers for those searching in the future.